# JQuery not working on site or locally but works in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JQuery is not running on my site or locally. Here is my site: http://michigangurudwara.com/pclass/

I'm simply testing out JQuery by trying out the show/hide functions. When you hover over "Test", more text should drop down underneath it. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://jsfiddle.net/nGY6K/2/

Anyone know why it's not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not linking to jQuery correctly.

Change this:

```
<link langauge="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="jquery.js" />
```

to this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: You edited your answer after GregL said that. Before, you had `<link ...` in both locations.

Comment: @Interrobang - It must have saved automatically/accidentally while I was typing.

Answer (score 3):

```
<link langauge="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="jquery.js" />
```

This is not the way to load scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

This is the way to load scripts. (edited to make it more sensible)

Comment: This syntax will give you a lot of headaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: Also, "language" is spelt wrong, and that attribute is not necessary any more (it [has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)).

Comment: True - didn't even notice that. And since it's optional, nothing complained. Edited.

Comment: @GregL - He's using the xHTML doctype.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Still, `type` is the only required attribute.

Comment: Until Google succeeds in getting cross-browser support for Dart (I really hope they don't).

Comment: @JosephSilber: If so, it will have its own mimetype, and no implementing browser would be silly enough to execute `text/javascript` as Dart code. `type` is enough.

Comment: @gsingh2011 Because I think a lot of browsers assume that the contents of a `<script>` tag will be javascript (which is true in most cases, really).